# will Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 upgrade resolved memory leaks?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks

Currently, i'm getting:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

The app is deployed in tomcat 6. In some way, when i upgrade to the tomcat 7 environment, will this issue be resolved?

I cannot do it right now because it is on a production environment.I would like to know if upgrading will help.

Comment: Treat the cause, not the Symptoms...!

Comment: Yeah, that's what i'm doing, currently profiling my application. but what i want to know if this will help me for the mean time. the app is kind of old and planning to refactor the code or probably rewrite it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app is deployed in tomcat 6. In some way, when i upgrade to the tomcat 7 environment, will this issue be resolved?

It is (IMO) highly unlikely that changing your Tomcat will solve the problem.

> the app is kind of old and planning to refactor the code or probably rewrite it

A refactor / rewrite is not *necessarily* required either.  What you actually need to do to fix a memory leak is to use a memory profiler and track down what is leaking the memory.  It could be something that is easy to fix, once you've tracked it down.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat is very unlikely the casuse. Tomcat 6 should be stable enough. Try to run visualvm and look at the memory consumption over time. Have you even considered increasing the heap size, maybe your margin is too small?

Comment: I would REALLY start there.